# Graphing an inequality to solve a mathematical model

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An appliance manufacturer estimates that the profit $y$ (in dollars) generated by producing $x$ cooktops per month is given by the equation $$y=10x+0.5x^{ 2 }-0.001x^{ 3 }-5000$$

where $0\le x\le 450$

a) Graph the equation
b) How many cooktops must be produced to begin generating a profit?
c) For what range of values of $x$ is the company's profit greater than $15,000?

- Steps that I took to attempt to solve this problem:

First, I simply plotted the given equation on my graphing calculator without manipulating it in any way. I ended up with a line that needed the viewing rectangle to be greatly enlarged in order to see it.

Next, I checked where the line intercepted the $x$ axis because it would be at this point in which the $y$ values started to become greater then 0. I zoomed in at the point of interception and realized it would be at $x = 100$. I believe this means that they need to produce 100 cooktops to start generating a profit.

Finally, I realized that the last part of the question is simply stating: 
$$10x+0.5x^{ 2 }-0.001x^{ 3 }-5000>15000$$

I manipulated the equation by subtracting $15000$ from each side and ending up with $$10x+0.5x^{ 2 }-0.001x^{ 3 }-20000>0$$

I plotted this new equation and found that the range of values of $x$ where it crosses the intercepts the $x$ axis is $(278,400)$

Am I correct? I feel like I am doing something very wrong here. Especially with part (C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

So your profit equation is defined by:

$$y = 10x+0.5x^{2}-0.001x^{3}-5000$$

So for part b, in order for the company to begin generating a profit, we must find the values where $y > 0$.

So we have that:

$$10x+0.5x^{2}-0.001x^{3}-5000 > 0$$

We find that the positive roots (since we don't want negative cooktops) is:

$$x = 100, 500$$

Now we must check the intervals to determine when $y$ is $> 0$ or $< 0$.

Looking at the graph of our function tells us that when $0 < x < 100 $, $y < 0$.

Also, when $100< x < 500$, $y > 0$.

Finally, when $500 < x < \infty$ $y < 0$.

So we conclude that at least $101$ cooktops (I assume it must an integer value) must be produced in order for the company to receive a profit.

You can perform a similar procedure for part c. You have set up the problem correctly.

Comment if you have questions.

Comment: so my answers:
b) $100$
c) $(278,400)$

are correct?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer for part b it would be $101$ since when $x = 100$ you have $0$ profit. The problem asks when there is a positive profit.

Comment: ah. I overlooked that little detail. And part c?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer also for part c you are correct. Now you must look at the graph to determine which intervals give the company a profit greater than 15,000. In this case, it would be when your new function is $> 0$. (The function is $10*x+0.5*x^{2}-0.001*x^{3}-20000$)

Comment: Well the line goes over the $x$-axis at $x=278$ and comes back down at $x=400$

Comment: So we can conclude when $278 \le x < 400$, the profit is a positive value, therefore, it will also be greater than $15000$. So the range of units would be from $278$ to $399$ units (remember that when $x = 400$ the profit is $0$)

Comment: Awesome. I can't believe I was actually right. Thank for your help.